# Is possible to get the SecuROM/GFWL Activation Key after the March 19 update of GTA IV?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-iv

The versions 1.0.7.0 and 1.0.8.0 released on Steam were activated with a SecuROM and Games for Windows Live key that was shown the first time that you open the game. This key could then be used to activate a Retail disc and use versions even older for modding like 1.0.4.0.

Is possible to get this key after the update of March 19, 2020?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Grand Theft Auto IV, the option to see the SecuROM/GFWL Keys was removed (it should be under Force Quit on the top-right corner).

[image]

For Grand Theft Auto Episodes From Liberty City, all of the existing licenses were removed from Steam accounts so it is impossible to open the game (I purchased it on June 30, 2017, and is asking to purchase it again).

[image]